# In Kotlin, what is the best way to make `String? + String?` return `null` if any of the inputs are `null`?

Tags: kotlin

### The problem:

Consider the following code:

```
val key: String? = "key"
val value: String? = "label"
val row = key + ": " + value
```

I would like the variable `row` to be `null` if any of the supplied inputs in the concatenation is `null`.

By default, any `null` String will be converted to `"null"` and the concatenation will proceed. In example:

```
val value = null
"Height: " + value + "mm" // Produces: "Height: nullmm"
```

I can skip the showing `"null"` in the results by using `value ?: ""`, but this solves only a part of my problem:

```
val value = null
"Height: " + (value ?: "") + "mm" // Produces: "Height: mm"
```

### My best solution so far:

I understand that writing a simple function like the one below would do the job, but I still expect that something like this already exists in the language:

```
fun Array<String?>.nullSafeConcat(): String? {
    val result = StringBuilder()
    this.forEach {
        if(it == null) return null
        result.append(it)
    }
    
    return result.toString()
}
```

### The ask:

Is there a better way to do this?

### **Post Scriptum:**

I cannot understand why would a null string be converted to `"null"` by default, as I cannot find any use case where this would be actually usable.

Comment: Null values being converted to "null" is extremely useful for logging. In practice, I don't see why Strings for user-readable content would commonly be nullable in the first place. A lack of content can be represented by an empty String. User-facing Strings are usually constructed out of some localization library rather than bare String concatenation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have an e-commerce app where each article has a finite list of attributes, of which not all are supplied by the merchant, which is represented as a `null` value. The labels for each attribute are hardcoded and localized, while the values are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves the problem, you can override the `+` operator on a nullable `String` to get close to what you want. For example:

```
private operator fun String?.plus(otherString: String?): String? = if (this==null || otherString ==null ) "null"  else this + otherString
```

Then:

```
    fun main() {
    val s1: String? = "Hello"
    val s2: String? = null
    val s3: String? = "Bye"
    println(s1 + s2)
    println(s2 + s1)
    println(s1 + s3)
}
```

prints:

```
null
null
HelloBye
```

The problem is it will only work with variables of `String?` not `String` which your `":"` value is. So you'd need to do something like:

```
s1 + colon + s2
```

where colon was also of type `String?`

EDIT:

There are two dangers with this approach. Firstly If you don't make it private (or even if you do) there is a risk that existing or new code tries to append two String? values and gets your new behaviour, which they don't expect. Secondly, someone reading the code where you call it may be surprised by the behaviour if they don't spot that you've overridden the `+` operator.

Comment: Ignore the previous edit about NullSafeString class. That bit was completely unnecessary

Comment: One risk with doing this is that you are effectively overriding the standard meaning of `+` for the package. It invisibly changes the standard, expected behavior of `+`.

Comment: That's neat.  But I think you'd have to document it _very_ clearly, as there's a significant risk of it being used unawares, and of being missed by people reading the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think [matt freake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66033682) is correct for the question, but I would avoid overriding the `+` operator for Strings - it can cause tons of unexpected issues.

Instead, I suggest you to slightly modify your `nullSafeConcat` helper function to be a standalone function that takes `vararg` instead of being an extension function. Something like this:

```kotlin
fun nullSafeConcat(vararg strings: String?): String? {
    val result = StringBuilder()
    strings.forEach {
        if(it == null) return null
        result.append(it)
    }
    
    return result.toString()
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```kotlin
val merged = nullSafeConcat("foo", null, "bar", "baz")
```

**Notes:**
You might want to handle the empty case (when varargs argument `strings` is empty) specifically, depending on the outcome you want.
Additionally, if you want this to work for at least 2 strings (so a concatenation is actually meaningful), you can use a signature like `nullSafeConcat(first: String?, second: String?, vararg rest: String?)` instead.

Comment: Simplified implementation of the function: `return if (strings.any { it == null }) null else strings.joinToString("")` Side note: I think "nullSafeConcat" is a misnomer. Concatenation is already null-safe.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Correct, however that way would cause the array to be looped twice in the worst case (`o(2n)` complexity instead of `o(n)`). I agree with your point about the naming - better naming could be `concatOrNull` or something like that.

Comment: IMO, it's questionable optimization. Worst case with your version, it concatenates a bunch of Strings needlessly before it encounters a null, and concatenating is orders of magnitude more expensive than null checks. But it's an unnecessary debate anyway, since no one is going to pass hundreds of values to a vararg function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```kotlin
listOfNotNull("foo", null, "bar", "baz").joinToString()
```

Comment: This would remove the annoying "null" in the resulting string but would still produce an incomplete result in the end. In my case, it is much better to display nothing than a partial join.